# Intellij not able to resolve Geb content when located in external libraries

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, geb

We currently have a central repository that holds all our source code (including the Geb page objects), and a seperate repo for the full Geb regression suite which depends on the former page object module.

When working with tests that string a few static content defined Geb objects together, Intellij is not able to resolve them, so I get this:

[image: this].

However, if I manually add the page object project source as a module to the regression project, suddenly Intellij is able to resolve these items, like this:

[image: this]

This is also the case for people writing tests directly into the main project containing the page objects.

I know that Intellij has visibility of the decompiled page object code (when I do drill into classes in the page object project, I can see the original source code with no 'this code has been decompiled' type messages, so what is the difference between the two approaches?

Comment: I think this is Intellij's behavior regardless of if you are using Jars or source code. I believe this to be a bug on Intellij's side

Answer (score 1):

I have never tried reusing Geb pages and modules inside of a jar across multiple projects and I have no idea if IntelliJ is only able to autocomplete Geb content definition usages if it has sources of them and not compiled classes.

I think that the only person able to answer your question will be the original author of [Geb support in IntelliJ](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/groovy/groovy-psi/src/org/jetbrains/plugins/groovy/geb), Daniil Ovchinnikov. You can try filing an issue in YouTrack or point Daniil to this quesiton on [twitter](https://twitter.com/oldpa).